# Why is the key of my Associative Array a reference to a string and not the string itself?

Tags: autohotkey

I have the following string that contains product barcodes:

```
4016241030924;4016241030924;8710624237479;5900951254741;8710398162939;8710398162939;8710398162939;8710398162939;8710398162939;8710398162939;8710398162939;8710398162939;8710624296933;8710624296872;8710624223885;8710624223885;8711000341001;8711000341001;8711000341001;8710624260415;8710624260415;8710624260415;8710624260415;8710624260415;8710624260415;8710624260415;8710624260415;8710624260415;8710624260453;
```

What I want to do is:

1. Split the string by `;`
2. Create an [Associative Array](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Objects.htm#Usage_Associative_Arrays) where the `key` is the barcode and the `value` is the count of the barcode
3. Loop through the Associative Array and print the `key` (= barcode) and the `value` (= count)

Here's what I am trying:

```
BarcodesAssArray := Array()
BarcodeArray := StrSplit(fileContent, ";")
Loop % BarcodeArray.MaxIndex() - 1 {
    thisBarcode := BarcodeArray[a_index]

    ; Check if barcode already exists
    if (BarcodesAssArray[thisBarcode]) {
        BarcodesAssArray[thisBarcode] := BarcodesAssArray[thisBarcode] + 1
    } else {
        BarcodesAssArray[thisBarcode] := 1
    }
}

For key, value in BarcodesAssArray
    MsgBox, %key% = %value%
```

But instead of the key being the barcode it is some sort of reference to the barcode. This is what I get:

```
-333809963 = 1
204486651 = 8
430547597 = 2
430561191 = 1
430584127 = 9
43084165 = 1
...
```

What I expect to get is:

```
4016241030924 = 2
8710624237479 = 1
8710398162939 = 8
...
```

What should I do differently?

Comment: Can you show where the variable `fileContent` comes from?

Comment: It's read from a .txt file and is 100% correct

Comment: I'm not able to get the behavior you're describing. It's working as expected. You getting different values for the keys and even a negative one, kind of makes me think there could be some problem with handling the large numbers. Are you running some ancient non unicode/64bit version of AHK?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Your problem is probably occurring because the keys in your arrays are being treated as numeric. There are limits on the size of numeric keys, depending on whether you are using 32 bit AutoHotkey or 64 bit. The way I would fix this is to cause the keys to be treated as alpha by appending a constant alpha value to the key in the array and stripping it off when displaying, etc the key. This also deals with the case where leading zeros would otherwise be stripped from the numeric keys."

TAC109 - https://www.autohotkey.com/boards/viewtopic.php?p=312566#p312566

---

```
BarcodesString := "4016241030924;4016241030924;8710624237479;5900951254741;8710398162939;8710398162939;8710398162939;8710398162939;8710398162939;8710398162939;8710398162939;8710398162939;8710624296933;8710624296872;8710624223885;8710624223885;8711000341001;8711000341001;8711000341001;8710624260415;8710624260415;8710624260415;8710624260415;8710624260415;8710624260415;8710624260415;8710624260415;8710624260415;8710624260453;"

BarcodesString := RTrim(BarcodesString,";")    ; remove trailing ;

BarcodesAssArray := {}

Loop, Parse, BarcodesString, `;
    switch BarcodesAssArray.HasKey(A_LoopField . "")
    {
        case true:BarcodesAssArray[A_LoopField . ""] += 1
        case false:BarcodesAssArray[A_LoopField . ""] := 1
    }

For key, value in BarcodesAssArray
    MsgBox, %key% = %value%
```

Xtra - https://www.autohotkey.com/boards/viewtopic.php?p=312565#p312565

Answer (score 0):

Try to simplify the code and take it one step at  time

BarcodesAssArray := 4016241030924;4016241030924;8710624237479;5900951254741;8710398162939
BarcodeArray := StrSplit(BarcodesAssArray, ";")

MsgBox BarcodeArray(1) BarcodeArray(2) BarcodeArray(3) BarcodeArray(4) BarcodeArray(5)

This will at least get you past the StrSplit statement knowing that you have a valid array

I haven't coded in a while so run at your own risk :)